# How can I create a key/value pair column in Azure Synape Data Flow?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

In Hive, I can create a column with a data type `column_name MAP<STRING,STRING>`

I can then use the `MAP` function to populate key/value pairs `MAP('name','bob','age','35')` etc

This looks like `{"name":"bob","age":"35"}` in the Hive table.

I can then select the value `select column_name(['name']) as my_name from my_table` which gives me the value of 'bob' in the my_name column.

How can I replicate this functionality in an Azure Synapse/Data Factory data flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Map data type in data flows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview#data-flow-data-types.

To set it use syntax like:

['name'->'bob','age'->'35']

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This works perfectly within a single data flow, and I can use column_name['name'] to retrieve the value. But when I write the output to a parquet file and try to read in another data flow. I get a validation error. The columns is showing as a string and the data looks like ```{"name":"bob","age":"35"}``` in Data preview. How do I convert that string to a map?

Comment: I'll post as a separate question and mark this as answered. Thanks.